# Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: ros, catkin

````
```
   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 266, in load_msg_from_string
    field_type, name = _load_field_line(orig_line, package_name)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 225, in _load_field_line
    raise InvalidMsgSpec("Invalid declaration: %s"%(orig_line))
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: Invalid declaration: ...
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python2" "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/service_node/cmake/service_node-genmsg-context.py"
  "-o"
  "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/service_node/cmake/service_node-genmsg.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em") returned error
  code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (em_expand)
  service_node/CMakeLists.txt:71 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:404: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
````

So i am new to ros and i am following a tutorial i created a package named service_node and then i created a srv inside it named AddTwoInts.srv

```
int64 a
int64 b
...
int64 sum
```

Then it asked me to created a scripts named client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import rospy
from service_node.srv import *



def add_two_ints_client(x, y):
    rospy.wait_for_service('add_two_ints')
    try:
        add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
        resp1 = add_two_ints(x, y)
        return resp1.sum
    except rospy.ServiceException as e:
        print("Service call failed: %s"%e)

def usage():
return "%s [x y]"%sys.argv[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        x = int(sys.argv[1])
        y = int(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        print(usage())
        sys.exit(1)
    print("Requesting %s+%s"%(x, y))
    print("%s + %s = %s"%(x, y, add_two_ints_client(x, y)))
```

and a server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTWoIntsResponse
import rospy
def handle_add_two_inst(req):
    print("Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b)))
    return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)
def add_two_ints_server():
    rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
    s= rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
    print("Ready to add two ints.")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_two_ints_server()
```

then i did some changes on cmakelist

such as unindented add_service_files

```
add_service_files(
   FILES
   AddTwoInts.srv
#   Service2.srv
 )

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

 catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
   scripts/server.py scripts/client.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

also so i edited the pacakge.xml and unindented the message_runtime

and when i try to run

```
catkin_make
```

idk why i get the error

Comment: So you followed these two tutorials ([this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv))?
One thing that jumps to my eyes is that you have used three dots `...` instead of three dashes `---` inside the message definition. This might be one possible reason for it but I'll have a look at your code later in more detail.

Comment: thanks it worked and but further when i try to run ``` rosrun service_node server.py . I am getting the following error                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/catkin_ws/src/service_node/scripts/server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTWoIntsResponse
ImportError: cannot import name AddTWoIntsResponse

Comment: Case sensitivity: `AddTwoIntsResponse` not `AddTWoIntsResponse`!